# is it possible to inject html into a toolstrip in a google chrome extension?

Tags: html, google-chrome, toolstrip, inject

How can i inject html into a google chrome toolstrip instead of buttons and the like?

Answer (score 0):

No, at the moment you can only add buttons to the right of or inside the address bar. These may open a popup that shows HTML however.